# Change orientation for all app from my app iOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have an app, I would like to change orientation for all app in iPhone from my app. So have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, The reason is iOS don't allow the Apps to access all OS resources.
I recommend that to understand iOS environment, its way different from other open source mobile OS. It won't give access to many important OS processes and features, either to change or perform any operation.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Project target settings]

Navigate to your target's general settings, as shown in the picture. The red box shows where you can change device orientation.

Comment: Thanks, but I want force orientation for all app(not only my app) from setting in my app.

Comment: You can, the most you can do is redirect the user to the setting menu of your device as the author said iOS won't allow you access or manipulate the settings or any resource of other apps.